# When can I access a form's members?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, controls, lifecycle

At first I tried this:

```
Public Class frmWait

Public Sub New(ByVal uWindowText As String, ByVal uInfoText As String)

    Me.Text = uWindowText
    Me.lblInfoText.Text = uInfoText

End Sub

End Class
```

But when I initiated the form like this

```
            Dim wait As New frmWait("blah", "blah")
            wait.Show()
```

... it told me "NullReference Exception" at this line:

```
Me.lblInfoText.Text = uInfoText
```

Settings the form's text worked fine. 
Okay, I subspected the label was just not created yet when I tried to set the text.

Then I tried the following. I stored the texts in a variable and wanted to set them when the controls have been created. I thought "Form_Load" was a good event for that:

```
Public Class frmWait

Private m_sWindowText As String = ""
Private m_sInfoText As String = ""


Public Sub New(ByVal uWindowText As String, ByVal uInfoText As String)

    'we can not set the texts right away because lblInfo does not seem to exist yet

    m_sWindowText = uWindowText
    m_sInfoText = uInfoText

End Sub

Private Sub frmWait_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.Text = m_sWindowText
    Me.lblInfoText.Text = m_sInfoText

End Sub

End Class
```

But it threw the same error. 
Ehhhhh, when exactely can I set the control's text?
Did I make any beginner's mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't delete what the designer does :) It's trying to help you. When you Create the

```
Public Sub New(...)
```

on a form, it will automatically put in :

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

The `InitializeComponent()` is required to get the form ready for you to work with it.

Comment: Thank you, but when I created the form, this event was not there (or invisible). Since I added the new "New" event manually, I had to place "InitializeComponent" by myself anyway, I guess. I am using VS2010. Only if I manually select the New event from the list of the form's events, it is placing the New event on my Form1.vb code. I guess if I do not select/access it, it still there, but simply hidden, so I did not notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the InitializeComponents call:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal uWindowText As String, ByVal uInfoText As String)
  InitializeComponents()

  m_sWindowText = uWindowText
  m_sInfoText = uInfoText
End Sub
```

The method call loads all of the controls that were created using the designer.  Without that call, your form is empty.